# How to preselect options when using select2 multiple select box with an ajax data source

Tags: jquery, flask, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a table in a form in a flask app with a select2 multiple select dropdown in each row of the table. In the table in the template file I have:

`<select name="visible_bonuses[{{ country.id }}]" class="bonus-multi-select country-{{ country.id }}" multiple></select>`

And in the script tag I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var country_id_to_bonus_ids = JSON.parse('{{ country_id_to_bonus_ids | tojson | safe }}');

        $('.bonus-multi-select').each(function () {
            var country_id = $(this).attr('class').match(/country-(\d+)/)[1];
            var selected_bonuses = country_id_to_bonus_ids[country_id];

            $(this).select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/settings/countries/bonuses/data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        var results = $.map(data, function (item) {
                            var selected = selected_bonuses.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
                            return {
                                id: item.id,
                                text: item.id + ' - ' + item.name,
                                selected: selected,
                            };
                        });

                        // Set the 'selected' property to true for options that are in the 'selected_bonuses' array
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            if (selected_bonuses.indexOf(results[i].id) !== -1) {
                                results[i].selected = true;
                            }
                        }

                        return {
                            results: results
                        };
                    }
                },
                placeholder: 'Select bonuses',
                width: '100%',
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried setting the `select` value to true. I have also created a new end point for the values that I wanted selecting and then tried adding those values to the other values as suggested in the [docs here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items). When I tried that technique, I used the following code but it wouldn't populate the preselected tags with the ID or name and therefore when the form was resubmitted, it would error.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var country_id_to_bonus_ids = JSON.parse('{{ country_id_to_bonus_ids | tojson | safe }}');

        $('.bonus-multi-select').each(function () {
            var country_id = $(this).attr('class').match(/country-(\d+)/)[1];
            var selected_bonuses = country_id_to_bonus_ids[country_id];

            console.log(selected_bonuses)

            $(this).select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/settings/countries/bonuses/data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        var results = $.map(data, function (item) {
                            var selected = selected_bonuses.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
                            return {
                                id: item.id,
                                text: item.id + ' - ' + item.name,
                            };
                        });

                        return {
                            results: results
                        };
                    }
                },
                placeholder: 'Select bonuses',
                width: '100%',
            });

            // Fetch the preselected items and add them to the control
            var $control = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/settings/countries/bonuses/selected/' + country_id,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var $options = $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return new Option(item.name, item.id, true, true);
                    });
                    $control.append($options).trigger('change');
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```